# How can I preserve the closing img tag while generating the HTML using Phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I have simple use case as producing an HTML page using phantomjs. For simplicity I have created a plain HTML page. I use a javascript to open this HTML page and return the page contents as is. I execute this javascript through phantomjs command line. The problem is that my img tag in HTML has a closing tag. But the resulted HTML do not have this closing tag. This leaves my HTML as an invalid XML. I want a valid XML (or XHTML) at the end. But i guess phantomjs is applying some intelligence and removing my close img tag.

This is my HTML page "imagchart.html"

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <h2 class="header">Spectacular Mountain</h2>
    <img id="myImage" src="C:\Downloads\chart.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my test.js which opens the HTML page and produces the outer html.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('file:///C:/Downloads/imagechart.html',function(status){
  if(status !== 'success'){
    console.log('Open failed');
  }else{  
    console.log(page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
   }));
} 
phantom.exit();
});

page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    //console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
```

I am running the phantomjs on command line as follows:

```
phantomjs test.js
```

This is the output from the phantomjs engine. Notice the closing tag from img is missing:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <h2 class="header">Spectacular Mountain</h2>
    <img id="myImage" src="C:\Downloads\chart.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is, how can i prevent the removal of closing img tag? I want a valid XHTML at the end.

**Note:** I tried changing the DOCTYPE in my HTML but it did not help.

Comment: Try another PhantomJS version (e.g. v2.0.0). If it still doesn't honor it, I don't see anything that you can do short of parsing using your favorite DOM library and exporting it as XML.

Comment: Maybe try to change the mime type of the document to "application/xhtml+xml"?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys,
I got it working by just changing the file extension from imagchart.**html** to imagchart.**xhtml**
This did the trick and now I get the closing tag for my IMG element.

Thanks.